# How to automatically assign/copy all fields from an object A to object B without cloning?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, data-driven

### Context: A non-intrusive way to reload objects when their description file is changed

[image]

---

#### Focus: adding dynamic reloading of objects with minimal changes to the existing codebase

Function called by `FileSystemWatcher` or alike:

```
void OnFileChanged(string filename, ...)
{
  var old3 = GetAssetByFilename(filename);
  var new3 = LoadAsset(filename);
  ...
  Utils.CopyFields(new3, old3);
  ...
}
```

---

#### Notes:

- Cloning won't work because all objects would point to the old copy
- There are multiple multiple similar lists of assets
- Changing `LoadAsset` function is a no-go, there are multiple `Load*` functions to change
- Changing `Asset` clases is no-go
- Copying has to include private fields, etc.

### Question: How to copy fields automatically (or is there a better way to do this)?

Comment: Is this some kind of project specs/requirements?

Comment: Are the objects the same?

Comment: No, it's not project specs/requirements. I'm trying to provide context why copying all the fields seems necessary.

Comment: The objects are of the same type.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have existing "non-automatic" way you want to improve? How you are getting list of "fields to copy" (i.e. is reflection ok)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961248/copy-properties-between-objects-using-reflection-and-extesnion-method

Comment: What is the condition to copy a property? Does `Utils.CopyFields(new3, old3);` copy ALL fields regardless of their values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the job:

```
public static class Utils 
{
    public static void CopyFields<T>(T source, T destination)
    {
        var fields = source.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach(var field in fields)
        {
            field.SetValue(destination, field.GetValue(source));    
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cloning... e.g. all references would point to the "old copy"

Comment: Cloning would be if a new object was created. This function just copies the fields. In use it would copy fields from newly loaded object into the old object so that the references to the old object would still remain intact.

Comment: "cloning" as described by the OP--which he didn't want.